# supremum and infimum understanding

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I looked at definitions and questions already posed, but none
helps in clarifying this specific challenge I am trying to understand.

Assume x $\in$ X = {1,2,3,4,5,6,8}

and I want

- inf{ x | x $\geq$ 5.5 } = 6
- sup{ x | x $\leq$ 5.5 } = 5
- inf{ x | x $\geq$ 8 } = 8
- sup{ x | x $\geq$ 8 } = 8

Is this correct? What I'm wary about is that some
might argue that

- inf{ x | x $\geq$ 5.5 } = 5

Comment: Don’t worry:  $5\not\ge5.5$

Comment: I just dont understand then what the difference is if 5 is also an answer choice.

Comment: From $\{x \in X| x \ge 5,5\}=\{6,8\}.$ Thus $ \inf \{x \in X| x \ge 5,5\}=6.$

Comment: For what it's worth, 'inf' applied to a finite set is the same as applying 'min' to that finite set, and 'sup' applied to a finite set is the same as applying 'max' to that finite set. Note that all your sets are finite -- indeed, all are subsets of a 7-element set.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro :thank I didn't know this.

Comment: @Fred : thanks. maybe one last one question.